# Python OOP inheritance use cases and calling inherited object

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, tkinter

I am trying to call the instance variable of my inherited class account_validation from my PageTwo class. I think i may be getting the error because of my inhertied class selfService, which main functions is to display various tkinter windows. Credit to @bryan oakely for the interface

```
 class selfService(tk.Tk, Toplevel):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

     selfService.database = Database()

     self.employeeWindow = None
     tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


     self.container = tk.Frame(self)
     self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
     self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
     self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
     self.frames = {}


     selfService.restart = False

     for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

         self.frame = F(self.container, self)

         self.frames[F] = self.frame

         self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

     self.show_frame(StartPage)


     def show_frame(self, cont):

         self.frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.frame.tkraise()



 class PageTwo(tk.Frame, account_validation):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):

         account_validation.__init__(self)
         print(self.test)

         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


class account_validation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'test'
```

I am subject to:

> > > print(self.test)
> > >          account_validation.**init**(self)
> > >       TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'

Furthermore, I want to understand why people would rather inherit a class and access its properties that way instead of instantiating that class in another class and accessing that class properties that way? What is the best scenario for both? If I am using multiple class methods from the inherited class should I keep it inherited?